# How can I make spans from lengths in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of string lengths, and I want to make span indices from them. So given lengths `[23, 27, 47]` I want to produce `[(0, 23), (24, 27), (28, 47)]`. How can I do that?

Here's what I have so far. I'm not sure I'm on the right track:

```hs
makeSpans :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
makeSpans [x:y:xs] = [(x+1, y), makeSpans xs]
makeSpans [x:y] = (x+1, y)
makeSpans y = y
```

Comment: The pattern `[x:y:xs]` signifies a list with one element, `x:y:xs`, which itself is a list with at least two values, `x` and `y`, and the (possibly empty) tail `xs`. So you probably mean `(x:y:xs)` which is a list with at least two values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small example of what you want:

```
> let list = ["abc", "abc", "abc"]
> import Control.Arrow
> fmap (second pred) $ zip <*> tail $ scanl (\acc x -> acc + length x) 0 list
> [(0,2),(3,5),(6,8)]
```

Broken down, that is:

1. `scanl` the list, adding each word's length to the accumulator
2. Create pairs of each list item and its successor:

```
> zip <$> tail $ [0,3,6,9]
> [(0,3),(3,6),(6,9)]
```

3. Fix the pairs so that they don't overlap, using `second` to map on the second element of each pair (`pred` is equivalent to `(-)1`).

To me, this type of solution is easier to build up than writing recursive functions from scratch. And as a bonus, it reads like a pipeline, so no need to keep track of multiple levels of indirection and mind-boggling recursion.

Comment: Actually, `pred` is not equivalent to `(-) 1`, but to `subtract 1` or `\x -> x-1`. (Instead, `(-) 1` would be equivalent to `\x -> 1-x`)

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is a bit off, perhaps you would benefit from some structured learning materials?

You haven't really discussed bad inputs / edge-cases but this might give you a starting point.

```
makeSpans = go 0
  where go n (x:xs) = (n, x) : go (succ x) xs
        go _ [] = []
```

Comment: Maybe you should write it `makeSpans xs = go 0 xs` since it makes it more explicit and op seems to be a novice :).